# Diode equation.Needs understanding

Tags: diodes, power-electronics

Kindly explain this equation for me.I do not understand what it means and from where this equation comes out?it's a diode equation
$$
r^{\prime}_d = \dfrac{26\mathrm{mV}}{I_D} + r_B
$$

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Diode-resistance.php

Comment: What LvW says. This is an extremely useful fact that few people seem to be aware of for practical use. Ignoring rb which is lead etc resistance, a diode has a resistance of 26 Ohm.mA   That is the product of its resistance and the mA it carries is 26. So at 2 mA the diode resistance is 26/2 = 13 Ohm. At 100 mA the diode resistance is 26/100 0.26 Ohms (approximately in each case). This fact comes in useful in unexpected places in electronic life. eg Gain of a common emitter stage with no emitter resistor is   38.4 x Vload. 38.4?????? Sure. Say you had a 1k load and Ic was 1 mA Re is 26 Ohms...

Comment: ... Gain is Vload/Vre (where Re is internal to the transistor). So Vload at 1k and 1 mA is 1V. And voltage across Re = 26 Ohms = 0.026V. So gain = 1v/0.026V = 38.4. Hmmm. 38.4 = 1/0.026, the rest just drops out. People rise up in fury over that equation - and it will not make sense yet but months or years from now you will revisit it and have a "Wow!" moment

Answer (score 2):

A diode is a strongly **non-linear** electronic part. Hence, it is absolutely necessary to discriminate between static and dynamic (differential) resistances. Therefore, it is common practice to use capital letters (R) for static resistances and small letters (r) for diff. resistances. (By the way: Unfortunately, this general rule is violated by the contribution as contained in "learningaboutelectronics.com" as referenced in the first comment).

The **first** part of the equation under consideration is derived from the voltage-current relation of the **pn junction**, which is an exponential one and can be found in each textbook. It is derived from the differential quotient (slope) of the function Id=f(Vd) and contains with the "temperature voltage" Vt=26mV the temperature dependence of the unit (26mV for normal ambient temperatures). The **second** part (rb) is nothing else than an ohmic part (rather small) which contains the ohmic influence of the material between the external pins and the pn junction. This part has a linearizing effect for the Id=f(Vd) characteristics and comes into play for relatively large currents Id.

The **static** resistance of a diode is simply the ratio R=Vd/Id.

Comment: Good point about the use of capital letter R in the link in my comment. Hadn't noticed it when I added it.